# Add tuples to a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, while-loop, tuples

I  have a problem with a simple program; my aim is to add tuples to a list, put in input by the user. The while-loop should break when the user puts 0.

this is my code:

```
sList=[]
x=tuple(input("insert tuple (0 to stop): "))
while x!=int(0):
    sList.append(x)
    x=tuple(input("insert tuple (0 to stop): "))
print (sList)
```

The problem is that the while loop never stops, even if I put 0, where is the mistake?

Comment: Why would a `tuple` be equal to 0?

Comment: `input` returns a string. What do you expect `tuple('string')` to do?

Comment: loop never ends because `input` returns string so you need to `int(input())`

Answer (score 1):

Please read the following lines in order to understand how to fix the error in your code:

```
sList=[]
x=tuple(input("insert tuple (0 to stop): "))

print("x contains: " + str(x))
print("x type is: " + str(type(x)))

while int(x[0])!=int(0):
    print("x contains: " + str(x))
    print("x type is: " + str(type(x)))
    sList.append(x)
    x=tuple(input("insert tuple (0 to stop): "))

print (sList)
```

You are comparing the string (0,) to the int value 0.
This is why your version doesn't work as expected.
I've also added two more prints to better understand what the code is doing.

Once we understood the nature of the error and how to fix it I would like to ask you why using a tuple in this case.
Could using an int directly be a good idea?

We could also reduce the number of lines and remove duplicated code, here's another iteration:

```
sList=[]
x = None

while x != 0:
    print("x contains: " + str(x))
    print("x type is: " + str(type(x)))
    x = input("Insert 0 to stop: ")
    if (x != None) and x.isdigit():
        x = int(x)
        if x != 0:
            sList.append(x)

print (sList)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems in your code (as far as I have understand your issues):

a. You need to first convert the input from user (which will be string) to tuple. You can use:

```
t = tuple(int(x.strip()) for x in input("insert tuple (0 to stop): ").split(','))
```

b. You need to modify your `while` loop test expression to:

```
while len(t):
```

Assumptions that I have made:

1. You want the user to type comma separated values (Because having a single value tuple in your list doesn't make sense to me. Correct me if I have missed something)
2. You want to end your while loop if user hasn't entered any value (,i.e., has pressed the Enter key).

If my assumptions are correct, try this:

```
def check_int(s):
    if len(s) == 0:
        return False
    if s[0] in ('-', '+'):
        return len(s) > 0 and s[1:].isdigit()
    return s.isdigit()

sList=[]
x=tuple(int(x.strip()) for x in input("insert tuple (0 to stop): ").split(',') if check_int(x.strip()))
while len(x):
    sList.append(x)
    x=tuple(int(x.strip()) for x in input("insert tuple (0 to stop): ").split(',') if check_int(x.strip()))

print(sList)
```